# ec2-delete-tags not working

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am using ec2-api-tools-1.6.7.3.

I want to delete a tag using CLI:

I have the CLI commands properly configured.

When i run

```
ec2-delete-tags -O <aws_access_key_id> -W <aws_secret_access_key> --region <my_region> <instance_id> --tag <my_tag>
```

it returns

```
TAG instance <instance_id> <my_tag> <my_tag_value>
```

However I see that the instance still has the tag available with it.I have also tried refreshing the console still no help.

Comment: I am able to create the tags successfully though

Answer (score 2):

Please include the actual cli command you are running, and the actual output - not the syntax.

Likely the issue is you are facing (but I cannot tell as the actual command is not provided) is your syntax on the --tag field itself which should be either:

--tag "TagKey=TagValue", or 
--tag "TagKey"

Use the double quotes